# Alternative to Abiword, LibreOffice or Open Office under Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, openoffice, abiword

Actually I'm looking for a word processor with the folllowing features :

- Base Formatting
- Lightweight
- Stable & bugfree

It should work for common office work on quite old machines.

EDIT : It's better to give a more complete description of the situation. Actually I'm working in a press agency. The journalists work on Ubuntu machines, and until a couple of weeks ago they did use Abiword to prepare articles that are loaded into a CMS. OpenOffice was not an option because it's too heavy and slow. The problem is that they keep many documents and browser windows open at the same time, so the amount of RAM avaliable is very little. We upgraded to natty a couple weeks ago and Abiword came out with many strange bugs and crashes, and it has some problems with extra mark-up, so we decided to move from it. 
Actually the better option IMHO is Google Docs, but they are not really happy sharing their documents in the cloud. So resuming, the problems are :
- Openoffice/Libreoffice : too ram consuming
- Abiword : strange markup and not so stable

Comment: vim + markdown?

Comment: You're much more likely to get useful answers if you explain why Abiword and OOo don't work. Otherwise it's hard to tell what you are looking for.

Comment: I would say LaTeX, but you're probably going to be reading documents as well as sending them back in the same format. It's worth learning LaTeX anyway, and we have [a site for that](http://tex.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @new123456 : Actually Latex is one of my favorites, but our journalists need a program to prepare articles quickly for online publishing, and they are not so willy to learn a complete new way of doing it :)

Comment: Switch window managers from gnome to something lighter like XFCE or Obenbox or fluxbox. That'll free up a ton of memory, and maybe openoffice will work better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at **[LyX](http://www.lyx.org/)**, it's my favorite writing tool ever, and I think I've tried them all. It's easy to learn too.

[image]

Comment: Yes, I actually use LaTex and Lyx a lot, but they are too document-production-oriented (I mean, for printing or publishing). That means it's really not what we were looking for.

Answer (score 5):

Did you have a look at [KOffice](http://www.koffice.org/)? It also has a word processor.

[image]

However, if the problem with Abiword is stability, did you consider just downgrading to the version you used before? Might require a bit of fiddling to the library versions right (or at worst, a recompile), but there's no reason you can't continue using the old version.

Comment: actually that's how I solved it right now... but there is still an extra-markup problem when copy-pasting with it so I was trying to find a solution to get rid of it :)

Comment: Abiword is more stable now than it was.

Answer (score 3):

I am not familiar with Linux enough to give you a specific recommendation, but when it comes to software alternatives, I always check in this site:

AbiWord linux alternatives: http://alternativeto.net/software/abiword/?profile=linux&platform=linux
AbiWord online alternatives: http://alternativeto.net/software/abiword/?profile=linux&platform=online

Hope it helps.

[image: http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-sqRUcou9H9Y/TZ2hY5beehI/AAAAAAAABDc/Sc6dFlbnrD8/s1600/abiword+in+ubuntu+screeshot.png]

Answer (score 2):

If you can still run a web browser on these older machines, one solution could be to use [Google Docs](http://docs.google.com), or another option like [netEditr](http://neteditr.com/)(I just ran across that one now, I don't know how good it is).

Comment: mmm actually it should be a native program... Google Docs was proposed before but they did not accept it :)

Comment: @jst Oh, ok.  You might edit your question to indicate all of the rejected suggestions.  It will probably get you an answer you can use much more quickly :)

Comment: thx for the tip :) I edited the question

Answer (score 2):

While it's not FLOSS, there's a nice multi-platform office package from a German company called [SoftMaker Office](http://www.softmaker.com/english/ofl_en.htm). I tested a version three or four years ago on a Pentium III 500 and it was usable, but I don't know if the current version has higher requirements.

[image]

If you're willing to register, the 2008 version can be downloaded free of charge [here](http://www.softmakeroffice.de/index_en.htm). The upgrade price to the current version is 30 Euros.

Comment: thx, I'll take a look at it :).

Answer (score 2):

Try [Calligra-suite](http://www.calligra-suite.org). Based on Koffice.

- Words for text processing.
- Tables for computations.
- Stage for presentations.
- Plan for planning.
- Flow for flowcharts.
- Kexi for database creation.

[image]

Comment: Gareth, is this fork of OOo lighter and faster than the original, as Juan requested?

Answer (score 2):

Is [Ted](http://www.nllgg.nl/Ted/) too lightweight?

[image]

Comment: In my limited experience under Debian, Ted is *incredibly* unstable and blows up within about one minute of my starting to do anything.